# Parent Selector nested inside &:hover

Tags: css, less

I am using the Less parent selector to shorten my selectors:

```
.module-name {
 // styles go here
 &__sub-module-1 {
  //styles go here
 }
}
```

Now my problem is how to continue to use the parent selector for adding the module-name inside a nested :hover statement. E.g. on hover of sub-module-1 I want to change something in sub-module-2. Inside the &:hover statement, what does the parent selector refer to?

```
.module-name {
  &__sub-module1 {
   &:hover {
    &__sub-module2 {
     // on hover of .module-name__sub-module1 change something in .module-name__sub-module2
    }
   }
  }
}
```

If i write it like this it works, but it defeats the purpose of using the parent selector to automatically fill in the name of the module:

```
.module-name {
  &__sub-module1 {
   &:hover {
    .module-name__sub-module2 {
     // on hover of .module-name__sub-module1 change something in .module-name__sub-module2
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I hope I could adequately express my problem; any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent selector (`&`) will always refer to the full parent based on the level at which you are. For example at the first level of nesting, `&` refers to `.module-name`. In the second level, it refers to `.module-name__sub-module1` and in the third level, it refers to `.module-name__sub-module1:hover`.

> **Extract from Less Website:** Note that `&` represents all parent selectors (not just the nearest ancestor *or the overall root ancestor*)

*The emphasised part in the above statement is my inclusion based on the context*

For this particular case, you could assign the `module-name` to a variable and use selector interpolation like below to form the selectors.

The variable value would never change unlike the parent selector (`&`) irrespective of how many levels of nesting you have and at which level of nesting you are using it.

```
@module-name: mod-name;
.@{module-name} {
    &__sub-module1 {
        &:hover {
            & .@{module-name}__sub-module2 {
                // on hover of .module-name__sub-module1 change something in .module-name__sub-module2
                color: blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer. i was just hoping there was a more elegant solution. i suppose there is no way to go back in the chain? i tried the && selector but that didn't work either.

Comment: There are several open discussions about possibility to have also a "partial behaviour" of `&` parent selector, in order to target only last ancestor and not everyone. I hope that in the future could be considered.

Comment: @LucaDetomi: Do you have links to any Feature Requests? Maybe I can add my say also. I would definitely like to have that feature.

Comment: @Harry: in the official "[Issues Repo](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075)" :-)

Comment: Also notice that in [#1075](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075) the proposed syntax is `&(target-element)` and for this particular example it will result in even more verbose code than the "interpolated variable" method of the answer above. (I usually imply that an attempt to use Less nesting to solve BEM name redundancies is a flawed approach in the very root, these are orthogonal things except some simplest cases).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Agree with you on that. I did see the new proposal (post Luca's comment today) but I am still trying to get my head around. A bit confused (maybe not because of the proposal itself but other things).