# How to write LESS with a parent selector (not top-level)

Tags: less

If I want to write the following CSS in LESS:

```
.foo{
   color:red;
}
.bar .foo{
   color:blue;
}
```

I can write:

```
.foo{
  color:red;

  .bar&{
      color:blue;
   }
}
```

However if I had the following LESS:

```
.top-level
   .foo{
     color:red;

     .bar&{
         color:blue;
      }
   }
}
```

This would produce a class of:

```
.bar .top-level .foo
```

How can I have `.bar` appear only one level above `.foo`?

Such as:

```
.top-level .bar .foo
```

---

The only way I can see to do this is the following code snippet, but it's not as neat as I'd like:

```
.top-level
   .foo{
     color:red;
   }
   .bar .foo{
      color:blue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possibly using a variable and selector interpolation like mentioned in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186972/parent-selector-nested-inside-hover/28187132#28187132). There is a feature request in pipeline that may make this easier though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to avoid multiple selectors here, however I believe that rearranging your selectors might make the code "clearer" :

```
.foo {
  .top-level & {
    color: red;
  }

  .top-level .bar & {
    color:blue;
  }
}
```

This way you clearly identify that your styling two instances of the class `.foo` based on their parents. Not as neat as what you wanted, but pretty cool still.