# How to select first parent element in LESS

Tags: css, less

```
.about-board {position: relative;text-align: center;
    &__img {position: relative;left: 0;top:0;width: 100%;height: 100%;display: block;
        .about-board:hover & {background: @pomeg;background: fade(@pomeg, 72%);}
    }
    &__desc {width: 100%;bottom: 0;left: 0;position: absolute;background: #2d1e1d;background:rgba(45,30,29,0.87);.transition(all 0.7s ease 0s;);padding: 20px;color: #fff;
        .about-board:hover & {top: 100%;bottom: auto;background: #2d1e1d;}
    }
}
```

This is my LESS code, what I want is to know, a direction/method to select .about-board, because, when I use & - it selects direct above parent. 
is it really possible?

/******************  Is there some way to achieve something like this ?*****************************/

```
.about-board {position: relative;text-align: center;
    &__img {position: relative;left: 0;top:0;width: 100%;height: 100%;display: block;
        &&:hover & {background: @pomeg;background: fade(@pomeg, 72%);}
    }
    &__desc {width: 100%;bottom: 0;left: 0;position: absolute;background: #2d1e1d;background:rgba(45,30,29,0.87);.transition(all 0.7s ease 0s;);padding: 20px;color: #fff;
        &&:hover & {top: 100%;bottom: auto;background: #2d1e1d;}
    }
}
```

I don't want to write that .about-board again and again., I tried this just above shown && method, but it doesn't works this way.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186972/parent-selector-nested-inside-hover/28187132#28187132).